# implement react-router within typescript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a working copy of the same code only differs come from typescript.
And this the code below somehow and exception message..

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import User from '../User/User';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

class Layout extends React.Component<{},{}> {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/user/:id" userid="25" component={User}/>
        <Route component={Notfound}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
  </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
and one of my component, home.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component<{},{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        Welcome Home Page!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Whats wrong here ?

Comment: what's the "exception" message?

Comment: @QoP hi, sorry forget to upload pic.

Comment: For components without props/state, use `any` as the type, e.g. `class Home extends React.Component<any, any> {`. Not sure if it's what's causing the error, but seems likely.

Comment: @zeh hey man I did you said and error is gone.. can you eloborate why you feel its solution.. then I happily accept it as answer of post.

Comment: It's because `any` is any type of parameter, while `{}` is a single object with no properties, which I assume is now supported by TypeScript as a type because of the new union types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the problem. As a commenter explained, there is some confusion for the compiler on how to explicitly handle passing in props.

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './App.css';

interface State { }

// tslint:disable-next-line
class App extends React.Component<any, State> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        HIIIII
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx:

```
...

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

I have not found a better solution yet. But this will indeed work.